# Is it possible to embed an excel pivot graph as a webpart?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, charts, web-parts

I have published my Excel workbook (which is one sheet with pivot-data linked to SQL Server and one sheet with stacked graph based on that data) to sharepoint 2010, and can view the chart fine via excel services xlviewer.aspx

I would now like to have the chart shows on our team's front page, by embedding a webpart to show the graph.

I've been able to achieve this by adding a Page Viewer part (IFrame) that links to the workbook, but this doesn't seem ideal (it requires setting the height, and it shows all the extra toolbars etc.)

I tried to insert a Chart web part linked to the excel workbook, but I do not know how to specifify the range name - I tried to use the same data range as in the pivot chart in my workbook ([Workbook.xlsx]WorkSheet!PivotTable), but I get the error:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Does anyone know if what I want it possible?

Comment: That's not very helpful... how?

Comment: Got a bit further... looks like it doesn't like linking to the Pivot Chart... it's fine linking to a standard range. Unfortunately, it's a pivot that I want to view :(

Comment: I think this will help. http://grounding.co.za/blogs/neil/archive/2007/12/29/creating-a-pivot-table-in-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todd has answered it above (thanks!)

Basically I (being a sharepoint novice) failed to find the Excel Web Access web part... once I'd got this, it was easy!